# How to reboot host into cgroup1 mode?

Tags: kernel, lxc, cgroup

On an ubuntu 22 Jammy host.
Created lxc containers for centos7 or centos8-Stream.
But they don't work.
Having [asked](https://is.gd/UzFGWM) on the LXC forum, I got an answer

> Chances are your system is running in cgroup2 mode, that’s not supported by centos7 and prvents it from starting up. You will need to reboot your host into cgroup1 mode to fix this.

How do I reboot my host into cgroup1?

This output might be helpful:

```
lxc-checkconfig
```

returns:

```
LXC version 5.0.0~git2209-g5a7b9ce67
Kernel configuration not found at /proc/config.gz; searching...
Kernel configuration found at /boot/config-5.15.0-48-generic
--- Namespaces ---
Namespaces: enabled
Utsname namespace: enabled
Ipc namespace: enabled
Pid namespace: enabled
User namespace: enabled
Network namespace: enabled

--- Control groups ---
Cgroups: enabled
Cgroup namespace: enabled

Cgroup v1 mount points: 


Cgroup v2 mount points: 
/sys/fs/cgroup

Cgroup v1 systemd controller: missing
Cgroup v1 freezer controller: missing
Cgroup ns_cgroup: required
Cgroup device: enabled
Cgroup sched: enabled
Cgroup cpu account: enabled
Cgroup memory controller: enabled
Cgroup cpuset: enabled

--- Misc ---
Veth pair device: enabled, loaded
Macvlan: enabled, not loaded
Vlan: enabled, not loaded
Bridges: enabled, loaded
Advanced netfilter: enabled, loaded
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_MASQUERADE: enabled, not loaded
CONFIG_IP6_NF_TARGET_MASQUERADE: enabled, not loaded
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_CHECKSUM: enabled, not loaded
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_COMMENT: enabled, not loaded
FUSE (for use with lxcfs): enabled, not loaded

--- Checkpoint/Restore ---
checkpoint restore: enabled
CONFIG_FHANDLE: enabled
CONFIG_EVENTFD: enabled
CONFIG_EPOLL: enabled
CONFIG_UNIX_DIAG: enabled
CONFIG_INET_DIAG: enabled
CONFIG_PACKET_DIAG: enabled
CONFIG_NETLINK_DIAG: enabled
File capabilities: 

Note : Before booting a new kernel, you can check its configuration
usage : CONFIG=/path/to/config /usr/bin/lxc-checkconfig
```

Comment: On the LXC forum they should be able to tell you how to do that, By the way your version info is confusing. Ubuntu 22 is a Ubuntu Core release and you use the word jammy. Please clarify the release.

Comment: thank you the version is 22.04.1 LTS